# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multiclass targets

Tags: classification, knn

I'm getting this error :ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multiclass targets

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred = knn.predict(x_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,pred))
print(classification_report((y_test,pred)))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,pred)
```

i'm not figure out the error in it, why it's coming?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like but maybe that helps: I had a similar problem, as I had multiclass data that scikit's classification_report wouldn't accept. What did the trick for me, was to flatten the variables `y_test` and `pred` so that both were just simple lists like so: [0,1,1,2,0 ...].